# Adjust 100% height or width of image as per parent div width / height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one dynamic/responsive `div` with image. And want to make image height or width 100% as per DIV height/width. I dont want to stretch the image. Either width or height should be 100% not both.

Here is the example that I am trying http://jsfiddle.net/CLrUS/

Comment: Are you looking to stretch it proportionally to fill? Or Fit? Do you want to center it, or have it aligned to the top? Or don't care about the aspect ratio, and just want it to fill the `<div>`? And do you know the aspect ratio in advance?

Comment: @Ktash It should stretch but keep maintain the original aspect ratio. Yes, It should be centre/vertically and horizontally.
No aspect ratio fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Give CSS for the Image like this

```
.css{ max-width:100%;

    max-height:100%}
```

Here the image takes the width of the parent div. Here image wont stretch, image gets the propotional height and weight

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/CLrUS/1/

Comment: Works great in Chrome. Does this work in all browsers?

Comment: @Mark Rummel It will work in all browsers....Firefox wil give little issue...thats also we can fix it....Firefox always take parent div width...

Answer (score 0):

for increase just height:

```
.class img{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

and this one for just width:

```
.class img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="#your image#" onload="imgFitParent($(this));" style="width:inherit; height:inherit;">

<script type="text/javascript">
function imgFitParent(imgElemt)
{
    if(imgElemt.parent().width() > imgElemt.parent().height()){ 
        imgElemt.height("100%"); 
        imgElemt.width('auto'); 
    }else{ 
        imgElemt.width("100%"); 
        imgElemt.height('auto'); 
    }
}

</script>
```

Like this:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CLrUS/3/)

Comment: Don't use functions for CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

use the min-width and max-width

```
img{
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Try resizing the panel

http://jsfiddle.net/e3yPT/